# Wifi behaviour with respect to DNS

Tags: wireless-networking, dns

I have a fibre connection which provides me internet thru the company provided router. Most of the time the internet connection just goes down; but what I observered is that when I changed my DNS server to google's(8.8.8.8) in windows, it worked. Simultaneously, I checked on my phone and it said no internet connection; then I downloaded a DNS changer app and connected to google DNS server, it worked(it still said in wifi settings that no internet connection was there, but internet connection was actually up).
The same thing happened in Ubuntu 18.04 which I have not yet checked for DNS settings; Here's my question now: My wifi connection was working even before I configured DNS; at times when the connection could not be detected by my phone or windows running desktop, I could access it by changing DNS server. What is happening here? Is this some sorcery or trick?

Comment: Configure your Wi-Fi router to use a static DNS server, not the one assigned by DHCP.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with WIFI - it may have to do with routing - especially if the company has provided a VPN on the router.

Comment: I can't change my router settings because the company didn't provide the admin password to the router portal(I have tried l lots of default passwords though), anyways I wanted to know what was happening and guess your comments gave me an idea, I'll look more into it

Comment: the ISP router should provide you access to DNS - if it doesn't work by default, definitively something you should ask the ISP to fix - this is a minimum expectation when you sign up for an Internet connection that it works OOB.